# Requirements on the endpoints of the confidence interval

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, inference

In a few statistics sources I saw the following definition of the confidence interval ($\mathcal{X}$ is a sample space):

> A $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for a parameter $\theta$ is an interval $(T_1(\mathbf{X}), T_2(\mathbf{X}))$ such that
>
> - $T_1(\mathbf{x}) \lt T_2(\mathbf{x}), \,\,\, \forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}$;
> - $P_\theta(T_1(\mathbf{X}) \lt \theta \lt T_2(\mathbf{X})) \ge 1- \alpha, \quad \forall \theta \in \Theta. $

But the first requirement
$(T_1(\mathbf{x}) \lt T_2(\mathbf{x}), \,\,\, \forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X})$ is omitted in most of other statistics textbooks and wikipedia.

So, do we really need this requirement in the definition above? Is it technically correct?
Maybe we should write it only almost surely ($T_1(\mathbf{X}) \lt T_2(\mathbf{X})$ a.s.)?

Comment: The second condition doesn't look quite right to me; it wouldn't seem to make sense for a discrete distribution to exclude the endpoints. Either you end up with an interval wider than it needs to be (to no benefit I can discern) or the probability statement would seem to be wrong.

Comment: @Glen_b That will be true if we define confidence interval as a closed interval $[T_1(\mathbf{X}), T_2(\mathbf{X})]$. But I defined it as an open interval $(T_1(\mathbf{X}), T_2(\mathbf{X}))$ and I'm not sure that I should include the endpoints in the second condition (i.e. write $P_\theta(T_1(\mathbf{X}) \le \theta\ \le T_2(\mathbf{X})) \ge 1- \alpha, \quad \forall \theta \in \Theta$)

Comment: Most people object when their data produces an unrealistic interval.  Examples are confidence intervals for probabilities whose lower endpoint is negative or upper endpoint is greater than $1.$  In such cases the interval can always be improved through the trivial expedient of limiting the endpoints so that they (a) lie within the set of possible values of $\theta$ and (b) are nonempty.  Without any loss of generality, then, you may assume these conditions *always* hold.